# dowload file with angular 6 and api drive

Tags: angular, drive

I've this problem when I try to download some files, the only one that working is .txt
Other file are corrupted.

```
  async downloadFromDrive(accountId: string, fileName: string, partNumber): Promise<boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{


 gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
return gapi.client.init({
  apiKey: this.API_KEY,
  clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  scope: this.SCOPES
}).then(() => {
  this.googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  this.googleAuth.signIn().then(() => {
    gapi.client.setToken({access_token: this.cookieService.get(accountId)});
    gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileName,
      alt: 'media',
    }).then(res => {
      let blob = new Blob([res.body], {type: 'application/pdf'
      });
      this.sortedFiles[partNumber] = blob;
      console.log('res-body',res.body)
      resolve()
    }) 
  })
});` });
```

LOG:

> âãÏ 3 0 obj <>stream
>   x�í]M��E�}¿DÁÿ�­ú�²��ÀMÜ»0{Á¬�¸r��� ���ÉF!d50`��
>   !à�A� !�H$´Ç9ÌñæÞê~ÝõªzfÌ=�Í{ÕU·>î©[�]Õ=��D"�H$��D"q�8|þ÷ý'/

Comment: Edit your question please - log is garbage.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: this log is result using console.log(res.body)

Answer (score 0):

you need add this in your request

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

something like this:

```
...
this.http.get(`${url}`,{
   responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers:headers}).subscribe(response => 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i try to add responseType but the file are always corrupted:

```
async downloadFromDrive(accountId: string, fileName: string, partNumber): Promise<boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
 gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
return gapi.client.init({
  apiKey: this.API_KEY,
  clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  scope: this.SCOPES
}).then(() => {
  this.googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  this.googleAuth.signIn().then(() => {
    gapi.client.setToken({access_token: this.cookieService.get(accountId)});
    gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileName,
      /* alt: 'media'*/
      alt: 'media',


    /* mimeType:'image/jpeg'*/
    }).then(res => {

       let header= new HttpHeaders({
         'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' +  this.cookieService.get(accountId),
         'responseType' : 'arraybuffer'

       });

       this.http.get(res.result.webContentLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: header} ).subscribe(res => {console.log(res);
       /*resolve()*/});
     console.log('download',res)
      let blob: Blob = new Blob([res.body],{ type:'mimeType'})
      this.sortedFiles[partNumber] = blob;
      console.log('res-body')
      resolve()
```